# Check ALL $_POST lengths

Tags: php

How can I check if all `$_POST` lengths are more than 4 before passing it further? Below is what I tried but doesn't seem to work.

```
if( strlen(preg_replace('/\s+/', '', $_POST))>3){
   //all POST lengths are at least 4
}else{
   //empty
}
```

Comment: Not my downvote Becky, but maybe you need to post the code related to your POST arrays.

Comment: @Fred-ii- Thanks. My requirement is to replace `if(!empty($_POST)) {` by a condition that checks if at least every post is more than 4 chars long.

Comment: @Fred-ii- I'm musing it to strip if any white spaces. `strlen()` does count whitespaces?

Comment: whats the meaning of `$_POST` length are more than 4 ?? do you mean more than 4 elements, more than 4 chars in value ??

Comment: @Fred-ii- it looks like she's trying to disregard whitespace while checking lengths

Comment: @iam-decoder yes, you're correct.

Comment: ah I see. Got it. I will delete all my previous comments then. edit: deleted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a loop

```
$valid = true;
foreach ($_POST as $val) {
    if (strlen(preg_replace('/\s+/', '', $val)) < 4) {
        $valid = false;
        break;
    }
}
if (!$valid) {
    // All $_POST must be at least 4 characters long
}
```

Comment: Added the whitespace removal.

Comment: hopefully she doesn't ever post an array

Comment: If the OP only has the one post, then why not just `if (strlen(preg_replace('/\s+/', '', $val)) < 4)` while taken from `$val=$_POST['var'];` and nothing else? Unless she has more than one POST array, then your answer is perfect. Edit: Ok, just noticed *"all POST lengths..."*. My mistake.

Answer (score 0):

`$at_least_four_chars` will contains all elements at least 4 chars

```
$arr = array(
    0 => "aaaa",
    1 => "bbbb",
    2 => "cccc",
    3 => "ddd",
    4 => "    a"
);

$at_least_four_chars = array_filter($arr, function ($value) { return strlen(trim($value)) > 3; });
```

so, only `0-2` elements will return as space doesn't count as a char